# How do i add and remove classes in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I achieve this piece of code with KnockoutJS, is it even possible?

```
$(document).on("click", 'input.effect', function () {
        var effect = $(this).val();
        if(effect == "max-height") {
            $(".nav-container nav").removeClass("opacity");
            $(".nav-container nav").addClass("max-height");
        } else if(effect == "opacity") {
            $(".nav-container nav").removeClass("max-height");
            $(".nav-container nav").addClass("opacity");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at the css binding handler docs, there are examples there too: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easier to read and extend if you think about it in a Knockout way.

Here's a jsfiddle illustrating the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/3QmDv/

HTML:

```
<div class="default" data-bind="css: navCssOption">
    Hello.
</div>

Nav style: <select data-bind="options: navCssOptions, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'css', value: navCssOption"></select>
```

The interesting part here is the `css` binding on the `div` which references the `navCssOption` observable.  This is the same observable that is bound as the `value` on the `select` element.

JavaScript:

```
var model = {
    navCssOptions: ko.observableArray(),
    navCssOption: ko.observable(null)
};

ko.applyBindings(model);

// Add some options.
model.navCssOptions.push({
    name: 'Semi-Transparent',
    css: "opacity"
});

model.navCssOptions.push({
    name: 'Restricted Height',
    css: "max-height"
});
```

The bindings on the `select` element use the `name` for options text, and the `css` is written to `model.navCssOption` when an option is selected.  This makes it suitable for use in the `css` binding on the `div` per [the documentation for the css: binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html).

Finally, the CSS:

```
.default
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.opacity
{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.max-height
{
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

You can see that adding / removing options doesn't involve editing if / then or jQuery click handlers, now it simply involves poking new (and quite readable) values into an observableArray.

Hope you can make use of this, and adapt to your scenario.

Comment: Wow, Awesome, exactly what I was looking for - Looks quite easy actually :)

Answer (score 0):

http://knockoutjs.com is for implementing MVVM design pattern in JavaScript. You would do this through data binding with the View Model.